# Find the attribute value of a tag using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Bangalore','value':'Bangalore','CID':'105','id':'105','P':'1','slug':'bangaluru'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Bangalore</li>
<li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Chennai','value':'Chennai','CID':'106','id':'106','P':'2','slug':'madras'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Chennai</li>
<li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Mumbai','value':'Mumbai','CID':'108','id':'108','P':'3','slug':'bombay'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Mumbai</li>
```

I want the `slug` value from `data-gs-ta-value` from each and every element using beautiful soup python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how you're getting the HTML fragment so I'll assume you have it as a string.

data-gs-ta-val is interesting because it looks like the associated datum is a string representation of a Python dictionary.

Therefore:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from ast import literal_eval

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Bangalore','value':'Bangalore','CID':'105','id':'105','P':'1','slug':'bangaluru'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Bangalore</li>
      <li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Chennai','value':'Chennai','CID':'106','id':'106','P':'2','slug':'madras'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Chennai</li>
      <li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Mumbai','value':'Mumbai','CID':'108','id':'108','P':'3','slug':'bombay'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Mumbai</li>
    </body>
  </html>
"""

soup = BS(html, 'lxml')

for li in soup.find_all('li', class_='gs_ta_choice'):
    d = literal_eval(li['data-gs-ta-val'])
    print(d.get('slug', 'No slug here'))
```

**Output:**

```
bangaluru
madras
bombay
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

html_doc = """
<li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Bangalore','value':'Bangalore','CID':'105','id':'105','P':'1','slug':'bangaluru'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Bangalore</li>
<li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Chennai','value':'Chennai','CID':'106','id':'106','P':'2','slug':'madras'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Chennai</li>
<li class="gs_ta_choice" data-value="Bangalore" data-gs-ta-val="{'text':'Mumbai','value':'Mumbai','CID':'108','id':'108','P':'3','slug':'bombay'}" style="line-height: initial;"> Mumbai</li>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    data = li.attrs['data-gs-ta-val'].replace("'", '"')
    data = json.loads(data)
    #print(data)
    print(data['slug'])
```

gives what you want